# Using Model on less variables

Tags: predictive-models

Something I've been confused about for a while, If I built a predictive model on say, 10 variables and predicted a test set with that model, could I then use those predictions as a training set and build another model but using fewer columns.

This is for the case when I have customer data with varying amounts of information depending on how long they have been with us.

Comment: That does not seem to make a lot of sense. Why don't you use the original data and fit a model with fewer variables? This allows you to quantify the loss of information.

Comment: yeah this makes sense to me, I was just curious as I've never seen it done before